# Arrange items in listview at the center

Tags: java, android, listview

This is my list view which is showing a list but in a ugly way . Please tell me how to arrange the numbers in a ordered manner.
[image]
 May be my question is not clear , ask me anything you want .

Here is the code for adapter

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,combination);

        ListView listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: show your code of adapter...

Comment: Do you want the numbers in an ordered manner or in the center? Your question and post have contrasting statements

Comment: I want the number at the center

Comment: you should use custom adapter

Comment: Please show me code that can help me

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Custom Adapter.
I described a full detail of how to make a custom adapter [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37084986/1607191)

The only change you need to do is to use two text view and give any style which you want to them.